# Comparar dos listas elemento a elemento en HASKELL

Tags: haskell

He estado buscando antes de abrir un tema pero no encuentro algo como lo que necesito.

Se da el caso que tengo que comparar dos listas con una determinada condición, elemento a elemento, pero soy incapaz. La función tiene que devolver un Bool, True si son iguales y False si no.

Esto es lo que tengo que hacer:
Los elementos que ocupan posición impar en la primera lista deben aparecer en
posición par en la segunda lista, pero en orden inverso.
Los elementos que ocupan posición par en la primera lista deben aparecer en
posición impar dentro de la segunda lista, y en el mismo orden.

Dado esto, mi código es el siguiente:

```
separarPorPosicion :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
separarPorPosicion [] = ([],[])
separarPorPosicion xs = (listaPar,listaImpar)
    where 
        listaPar = [ x | (x,y) <- zip xs [1..length xs], even y]
        listaImpar = [ x | (x,y) <- zip xs [1..length xs], odd y]

mellizas :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
mellizas [] [] = True
mellizas _ [] = False
mellizas [] _ = False 
mellizas xs ys = impar1 == reverse par2 && par1 == impar2
    where 
        par1 = [x | (x,y)<- separarPorPosicion xs]
        par2 = [x | (x,y)<- separarPorPosicion ys]
        impar1 = [y | (x,y)<- separarPorPosicion xs]
        impar2 = [y | (x,y)<- separarPorPosicion ys]
```

Me da un error de tipos que soy incapaz de resolver.
Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Resuelto! Era mucho más sencillo que eso. Ya que la función "separarPorPosicion" devuelve las listas separadas, no me hace falta separarlas nuevamente con las listas por comprensión, si no que quedaría así:
  
  `(par1, impar1) = separarPorPosicion xs  (par2, impar2) = separarPorPosicion ys`

Comment: La resolución no se indica editando el título, sino eligiendo una respuesta como aceptada (incluso una respuesta tuya)

Answer (score 0):

Todavía puede ser más sencillo.

Separamos el problema en dos:

```
-- comparar impares con impares
test1 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
test1 (x:_:xs) (y:_:ys) = x==y && test1 xs ys
test1 [] [] = true
test1 _ _ = false

-- comparar pares con impares
test2 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
test2 (x:_:xs) (_:y:ys) = x==y && test2 xs ys
test2 [] [] = true
test2 _ _ = false
```

Y hacemos la combinación:

```
mellizas :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
mellizas xs ys =  length xs == length ys 
               && even (length xs)
               && test1 xs (reverse ys)
               && test2 xs ys
```

Aquí hace la comprobación de que las dos listas tienen la misma longitud par. Por la propia construcción de las funciones `test1` y `test2` podemos darnos cuenta que estas funciones siempre devuelven `false` si las listas son de distinta longitud o si tienen longitud impar, por lo que podemos obviar este chequeo para hacer aún más simple la función `mellizas`:

```
mellizas :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
mellizas xs ys = test1 xs (reverse ys) && test2 xs ys
```